# The usage of the words "different" and "from"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, differences, comparisons

> How is the Coca Cola recipe different in the U.S. from the U.K.?

My question is whether this is the correct form of this type of question or it should be "from in the U.K." or even "from that in the U.K."

Comment: Both versions are fine. It's normal in English to "delete" predictably repeated elements such as ***the Coca Cola recipe*** and ***in*** in your context (which can optionally be "replaced" by ***that in/of***, or simply discarded altogether). I can't see any significance to the choice, which doesn't really seem to have anything to do with "correctness" or "level of formality".

Comment: While understandable, the sentence compares the soda recipe and a country: How is the recipe different from England? Can't we have "How is the Coca Cola recipe different in the U.S. **and in** the U.K.?"

Comment: ... Yes; I'd prefer 'How is the Coca Cola recipe in the U.S. different from that in the U.K.?' or perhaps 'How does the US Coca Cola recipe differ from that used in the UK?'

Comment: This is interesting for me, a speaker of British English. I find myself agreeing with the comments, but I thought that "different than", rather than "different from", was standard in American English.

Comment: @PhilipWood Many Americans would use "different than", but those who have gone beyond high school prefer _from_  (often found on SAT exams). It's like saying "like I said", rather than _as I said_.

Comment: @Cascabel Thank you. I had no idea. In England we also hear the dreaded "different to". And over the last twenty or thirty years, "like" has almost ousted "as" in many contexts. For example, it's rare to hear "as if" or as though" in a sentence spoken in England.

Comment: @PhilipWood I was, like, duh, like what you sayin? I don't get it. You, like, some sort o posh geezer or summat?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with all of these is that they come off sounding as though one were
comparing a recipe with a country:

1. How is the Coca Cola recipe **different** in the U.S. **from** the U.K.?
2. How **different** is the U.S. Coca Cola recipe **from** the U.K.?
3. How does the U.S. Coca Cola recipe ***differ from*** the U.K.?

Example (3) above leads to an immediate understanding of the error, and to its solution.

In comparisons of two things using *different* or *similar* and a preposition *to* or *from*, keeping the two words involved closer to each other results in a clearer construction than letting them drift farther away from each other does.

4. How does the U.S. Coca Cola recipe **differ from** the U.K.’s?
5. How is the Coca Cola recipe in the U.S. **different from** the one in the U.K.?
6. How is the Coca Cola recipe in the U.S. **different from** that of the U.K.?
7. How is the Coca Cola recipe in the U.S. **different from** the U.K.’s?
8. How is the U.S. Coca Cola recipe **different from** the U.K. Coca Cola recipe?
9. How is the U.S. Coca Cola recipe **different from** the U.K.’s?

If you do split *different* and *from*, you need to be careful to remain consistent in your comparisons
so that you are always comparing like things, not different things:

10. How different is the U.S. Coca Cola recipe from the one in the U.K.?
11. How different is the U.S. Coca Cola recipe from that of the U.K.?
12. How different is the U.S. Coca Cola recipe from the U.K.’s?

Now you’re still comparing one recipe with another recipe, not trying to compare a recipe with a country. It’s better this way because even though people will probably work out what you had meant, you shouldn’t ask them to. Instead you should state it more clearly in the first place by comparing only like things with each other.

Answer (score -1):

> How is the Coca Cola recipe different in the U.S. from the [recipe in the] U.K.?

The construction is grammatical but with ellipsis.

(S How is (NP the Coca Cola recipe (Adj Phrase different(PP in (NP the U.S.))(PP from [the recipe] (PP in (NP the U.K.)))))